# Passing data from from django view to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django

I'm trying to create a network using the vis.js library (http://visjs.org/) and django (the basic one - http://visjs.org/examples/network/basicUsage.html).
I need to pass data specifying the nodes of the network from django to javascript.
This is my views.py:

```
def create_network(request):
    r=[]
    for i in range(1,6):
        d={}
        d['id'] = i
        d['label'] = 'Node ' + str(i)
        r.append(d)
    data = json.dumps(r)
    return render(request, 'network.html', {"nodes":data})
```

This is the relevant part of my template:

```
  n = {{ nodes }}
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet(n);
```

When I run this, the {{nodes}} disappears and it simply becomes:

```
  n = 
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet(n);
```

and I get unexpected token errors. 
I'm relatively new to Django and javascript so sorry if this seems elemenatary. How would I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: It will definitely work... try remove cache and reload...

Comment: As @RajaSimon said, your code as you mentioned it would work, if the template `network.html` was exactly with the content you mentioned. Try to simplify your example even more and examine the returned html. Also, try renaming `nodes` key to something else, just in case it's reserved in the template engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 var n = `{{ nodes|safe }}`;
 var nodes = new vis.DataSet(n);
```

You may or may not need to add a `jQuery.parseJSON()` around the data before passing it into the `vis.DataSet`. I cannot say for sure because I have never used http://visjs.org/.